# Export from QGIS to Google Maps maintaining formatting

Tags: qgis, google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm totally new to QGIS so I'm not even sure this is possible.

I've created a bunch of polygons within QGIS and they look just like I want them (color, transparency, etc.).

What I'd like to do now is to export this somehow so that this same formatting is visible in a Google Map I'm creating as a layer. Is this possible? What format do I export?

I've tried exporting as geoJSON, but what appeared in Google Maps was not formatted. The boundaries of the polygons were there, but no colors, etc.

Comment: afaik this won't work with geojson but you might want to check the KML questions for pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to set the style in the script. This makes the GeoJSON more flexible than KML where this is done in the file itself. Use: map.data.setStyle and the fillColor option, like it is described in the documentation. You can even give each polygon a separate style based on your json data.